# Replace match with items in order

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a string in Java which contains a number of patterns. There is an array of values which needs to be substituted for each of this pattern in the string based on the order. Below is a sample of what the method should do.

```
public static String replaceValues(String withPattern, String... params){
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{\\}").matcher(withPattern);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int index =0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (args.length == index) {
            matcher.appendTail(sb);
            return sb.toString();
        }
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, params[index]);
        index++;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

```
// A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
replaceValues("A quick brown {} jumps over the lazy {}", "fox", "dog");
```

This works. I just want to know if there is a more efficient way of writing this code rather than being too declarative.

Comment: Where is the array `values` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) repeatedly to replace consecutively each param one by one.

```
public static String replaceValues(String withPattern, String... params){
    String string = withPattern;
    for (String param: params) {
        string = string.replaceFirst("\\{}", param);
    }
    return string;
}
```

Since [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) you can achieve the same using the [`Stream#reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method with the `withPattern` as the `T identity`.

```
public static String replaceValues(String withPattern, String... params){
    return Arrays.stream(params).reduce(
            withPattern, 
            (pattern, param) -> pattern.replaceFirst("\\{}", param));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also cheat `String.format` by giving it `%s` instead of `{}` (but it's advisable to test for performance if that aspect is critical to your application):

```
public static String replaceValues(String withPattern, String... params) {
    return String.format(withPattern.replace("{}", "%s"), (Object[])params);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have an issue when the number of params and the patterns aren't same?

Comment: @Apps There would be an exception if there are fewer values than there are placeholders, which is obvious.

Comment: What if `withPattern` contains`%`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern PAT = Pattern.compile("\\{}");

static String replaceValues(String withPattern, String... parms) {
    Iterator<String> p = List.of(parms).iterator();
    return PAT.matcher(withPattern).replaceAll(m -> p.next());
}


@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void testFormat() {
System.out.println(replaceValues(
    "A quick brown {} jumps over the lazy {}" , "fox", "dog"));
```

And

```
System.out.println(replaceValues(
    "A quick brown {} jumps over the lazy {}" , "fox", "dog"));
```

output

```
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```